# Difference in love2d compiler behaviour

Tags: android, compiler-errors, love2d

Everyone.
I've got strange error on line like

```
if a == 1 then
```

Most amusing, that on pc (win8, sublime text2, build option further below) it works perfectly. But on mobilephone (redmi, android 6.0.1, market app Love for Android 0.10.2) it shows an error *"=" expected near a*.

```
{
"selector": "source.lua",
"cmd": ["D:/love-0.10.2-win64/love.exe", "${project_path:${file_path}}"],
"shell": true,
"file_regex": "^Error: (?:[^:]+: )?([^: ]+?):(\\d+):() ([^:]*)$"
}
```

The program itself is very short and openly on https://github.com/Schmel924/Lovestub

Answer (score 0):

Your example project doesn't have a line `a == 1`. Are you sure the variable exists at the moment you're comparing it?

Comment: Well, i meant visible of course. Also i added visible = 0 into love.load, but error stays the same.

Comment: @Schmel924 Could you post the exact stacktrace, and update your github project?